# Обрезать ссылки внутри постов (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, ссылки

Нужно, чтобы все ссылки, добавляемые пользователями в свои посты (а у пользователей отключена админка, и они не могут оформлять ссылки с помощью встроенного редактора), обрезались (отображались) либо по заданной длине символов, либо до домена. Чем более грамотно это организовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот небольшой код, который я искал (файл functions.php):

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'content_filter' );
function content_filter( $content ) {
    $new = preg_replace_callback("/(<[Aa][\s]{1}[^>]*[Hh][Rr][Ee][Ff]=\"[\S]*\"[^>]*>)([^<]+)(<\/a>)/",
    function($m) {
    return $m[1] . substr($m[2],0,40) . '..' . $m[3];
    },
    $content);

return $new;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если обрезать только при выводе, то нужно использовать фильтр на the_content.
[Объяснение на русском с примерами](http://wp-kama.ru/hook/the_content)

Если же при помещении в БД - wp_insert_post/wp_update_post

Comment: То, что надо использовать фильтр the_content, логично, но как поступить внутри этого фильтра? Использовать какую-то php-функцию, которая обрезает у ссылки только её отображение? Потому что, если, например, я обрезаю отображение css-ом, то тогда я не знаю, что делать с картинками, которые оборачиваются ссылками.

Comment: Так ссылку всё же надо сохранить, а обрезать только анкор? В любом случае это делается с пом регулярок. Я бы рекомендовал делать это не при выводе (the_content), а при записи в БД. если они больше нигде не используются. И так и обрезка с пом css  вполне себе нормальное решение (если речь про анкоры ссылок. причём картинки - не понятно).

Comment: Да, обрезать нужно только анкоры. Согласен, лучше при записи в БД. Как раз регулярку то я и не знаю, как написать. Что касается css - вариант уже отпал. Нашёл функцию url_shorten, но ведь как-то надо найти все ссылки в контенте и в цикле передать каждую в эту функцию.. (?) Именно вот эти действия (сама обработка) меня интересуют.